# Path for folder that gets deleted when app gets uninstalled (Desktop-Bridge WPF .Net 6)

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, .net-6.0, desktop-bridge

How do I get the path for a folder that gets deleted when the app gets uninstalled? (For a desktop bridge WPF app with a "packaging project".)

I want to store information there that will be removed if the user uninstalls the app so that if they reinstall it they'll get the experience of a completely new install. Using the TMP folders is *not* enough, data there *can* get deleted. It usually does not.

I also can't use ApplicationSettings because those don't play well with the desktop bridge.

Comment: You usually do this by adding code to the uninstaller. Which uninstaller do you use?

Comment: @GerardoGrignoli As stated, this a desktop bridge application packaged by a "packaging project". (That's for the Windows Store.) There is no uninstaller.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Any file that you save to `Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData)` during the execution of a packaged app will be redirected to `%localappdata%\Packages\PublisherName.AppName_hash\LocalCache\Local` and removed when uninstalling the app.